# How Can I Find My Post?

Tags: support, specific-question

I posted a question before Christmas on 12/24 and had the *Notify* box checked with my email address provided. I did not have a registered account when I was posting my question but I did pick a tag "nhibernate".

Can anyone give me advice on this please?

Comment: Type in "nhibernate" in the search box to the top right. You'll get the last few week's results on one page.

Comment: this should be on meta.stackoverflow.com
use the search box on the top right to find it

Comment: Did you try the "search" box with your subject line?

Comment: belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

use search, belongs on meta etc. Agree with those who have left comments, but this is probably it

[Help with NHibernate Insert/Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959355/help-with-nhibernate-insert-update)

Comment: Yes! This is my post! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

By clicking your name on top of the screen, your profile will show your activity (currently [none](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239628/john) for the account you used to ask this very question; please ask "team" from "@stackoverflow.com" to merge [your old account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238343/john) and [duplicate account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239628/john), and also please associate your Stack Overflow and Meta accounts at [the account tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238343?tab=accounts#sort-top) of your profile). And clicking the little mail envelope next to your name even gives you some more details. If you set up an RSS reader [for your own profile](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/239628), then you can have that reader keep as much history as you want. And using

```
user:me
```

in [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame) will limit all search to your own contributions.

Comment: No need to spam-protect the email address---it's on the bottom of every page anyway.

Comment: I know, but one never knows when that changes, or how the public data dump is ever abused. I even don't quote last names from people in my posts, just in case people want to change that some day. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Arjan. That was my first ever post on stackoverflow. I was not quite sure how the site works. Looks like I need to spend some time to learn the tool. I like this site. There seems a lot of good posts and answers that are related to what I have been learning.

Comment: Hmm, a downvote. Maybe there's no cookie to provide links to profiles and feeds for non-registered accounts?

Comment: (I've already merged the accounts)

Comment: HOOORAY! There's a "user:me" search! I didn't know about that, thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your post has been found, but to make things even simpler I've merged your user accounts - so now you can click on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239628) to find it. Of course, to avoid losing it again you might want to create a registered account. It is free and won't require anything extra (you already have an OpenID via your e-mail provider).